# Downloading a file using Selenium, with up to 3 attempts

Tags: python, loops

Here is what I want to do:

1. Using Python 3 and Selenium, click a link to download a file.
2. Check every 50 milliseconds to make sure the file exists. Download the file again if it doesn't exist after 5 seconds.
3. After the file exists, check every 50 milliseconds to get the file size and make sure it has has more than 0 bytes. Download the file again if it's an empty file.
4. After the file exists and it has more than 0 bytes, check the file for nul bytes. If it has nul bytes, download the file again.

I want to try to download a good file for up to 3 times. After 3 attempts, I want to exit the script.

Here is basically what I have so far:

```
##### attempt to download a good file up to 3 times

loop_1 = 0
while loop_1 < 3:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download Results').click() ##### download the file

##### check the existence of the downloaded file; if not there within 5 seconds, download the file again

    loop_2 = 0
    while loop_2 < 100:
        f_exists = os.path.isfile('/Users/jeff/download.csv')
        if f_exists == True:


##### check file byte size is greater than 0; if not greater than 0 within 5 seconds, download the file again

            loop_3 = 0
            while loop_3 < 100:     
                f_size = os.path.getsize('/Users/jeff/download.csv')
                if f_size > 0:
                    break
                else:
                    loop_3 = loop_3 + 1

##### check if nul bytes are in the file; if yes, download the file again

                if '\0' in open('/Users/jeff/download.csv').read():
                    print("WARNING: THERE ARE NUL BYTES IN THE downloaded_file.csv FILE.")
                else:
                    print("there are no nul bytes in the downloaded_file.csv file")
                    break
            else:
                loop_3 = loop_3 + 1
                time.sleep(.05)
        else:
            loop_2 = loop_2 + 1
            time.sleep(.05)
    else:
        loop_1 = loop_1 + 1
        time.sleep(.05)
```

Comment: `while loop_3 < 100: ` block includes this code whether file has any length or not `if '\0' in open('/Users/jeff/download.csv').read():`, i would suggest to put another `time.sleep(.05)` after `loop_3 = loop_3 + 1`

Comment: added time.sleep(.05) and updated the above as suggested; still looking for an answer

Comment: How does it fail? At what stage does it fail? What should have happened at this stage?

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of great frustration, and some help from another question I asked, brilliantly answered, here's what I've come up with that works (at least, I haven't had any test I've thought up fail so far).

```
##### create functions

def file_exists():
    for j in range(0,101):
        f_exists = os.path.isfile('/Users/jeff/download_file.csv')
        if not f_exists:
            time.sleep(.05)
        elif f_exists:
            return(True)
    return(False)

def file_size():
    for j in range(0,101):
        f_size = os.path.getsize('/Users/jeff/download_file.csv')
        if not f_size > 0:
            time.sleep(.05)
        elif f_size:
            return(True)
    return(False)

##### attempt to download a good notes data file up to 3 times

loop_1 = 0
while loop_1 < 3:

    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download Search Results').click() ##### download file

    ##### check to make sure the file exists before further processing;
    ##### if not there within a short time, try to download the file again

    file_down = file_exists()
    if file_down != True:
        loop_1 = loop_1 + 1
        print("WARNING: THE download_file.csv FILE FAILED TO DOWNLOAD.")
        continue

    ##### check to make sure the file contains data (more than 0 bytes) before
    ##### further processing; if 0 bytes, try to download the file again

    file_down = file_size()
    if file_down != True:
        os.remove('/Users/jeff/download_file.csv')
        loop_1 = loop_1 + 1
        print("WARNING: THE DOWNLOADED download_file.csv FILE IS AN EMPTY FILE; 0 BYTES.")
        continue

    ##### check to make sure there are no NUL bytes in the file;
    ##### if there are Nul bytes, try to download the file again

    elif '\0' in open('/Users/jeff/download_file.csv').read():
        os.remove('/Users/jeff/download_file.csv')
        print("WARNING: THERE ARE NUL BYTES IN THE DOWNLOADED download_file.csv FILE.")
        loop_1 = loop_1 + 1
        continue
    else:
        break
```